# Absolute div not positioning correctly

Tags: css, position, css-float

I've got a div that sits inside another div and it's supposed to float above all of the other content in the div, and stick to the right of the div. To achieve this I had to set the div positioning to "Absolute" since when it is set to "Relative", it pushes all of the content to the side of it.

However, when positioning is set to Absolute, the div does not position correctly and sticks to the left side of the div instead of the right, causing usability problems. The div positions correctly when using Relative positioning, but not absolute.

I have tried setting the margin-left to the width of the div but the size of the div can change depending on the template the page is using. I have tried setting the margin-right property appropriately but the div moves when the browser is resized.

Expected result: http://puu.sh/479u1.png (this uses margin-right to position it but this was done to show simpily what was expected to happen - this cannot be used due to the unexpected movements caused when the browser is resized)

Actual result: http://puu.sh/479ya.png

CSS code for the floating div:

```
    .GBDragBoxOptions
    {

        position: absolute;
        z-index: 99;
        float: right;
        width: 400px;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to position the div to the right, then just use "right: 0px;" or something like that, in conjunction with "position: absolute;". As long as the parent div is positioned in some way (i.e. relative), that should do what you want.

Comment: I tried this, however it positioned the div all the way to the right of the page, when it should be aligned to the right of the div.

Comment: That's because the parent div needs to be relatively positioned. It will work then.

Comment: Okay, i've set the parent to be positioned relatively and used right: 0px; instead of float. Works fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Float does nothing on absolute positioned elements..

Use `right: 0;` instead of `float: right;`

Answer (score 0):

It's a absolute div, so why float, use top and right

```
.GBDragBoxOptions
    {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 400px; 
    top:100px;
    right: 50px;
    }
```

Comment: Tried this, but it positions it in a certain place and if the div gets smaller, the div doesn't follow those adjustments.